# Group messages by latest response in conversation threading

Tags: mysql

I need a simple internal messaging system between users.

My tables:

```
+--------------+         +---------------------+
|   messages   |         |        users        |
+----+---------+         +---------------------+
| id | message |         | id | username | ... 
+----+---------+         +---------------------+

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 users_messages                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | from_usr_id | to_usr_id | msg_id | thread_id | read | sent_at | read_at |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`INT 'thread_id'` represents the conversation thread, its used to group messages.

`BOOLEAN 'read'` represents if the user opened/viewed the message or not.

I want to group messages by `'thread_id'`, sorted by `'sent_at'` so I can show the user his   latest messages by thread. I want also to count the messages in each thread.

I want to get something like this for a specific user id:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| last_messages_by_conversation
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| message | from_username | sent_at | count_thread_msgs | count_unread_msg |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`TEXT 'message'` is the latest message in the specific `'thread_id'`

`VARCHAR 'from_username'` and `DATETIME 'sent_at'` are related to the latest message.

`INT 'count_thread_msgs'` and `INT 'count_unread_msg'` are related to the thread, representing the total number of messages and the number of unread messages in the thread.

Each row represents a thread/conversation (group by `'thread_id'`), showing the last message (sorted by `'sent_at'`) for that specific thread.

Comment: @eggyal: I didn't have the time to test it yet, I will do it tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be found by first grouping the `users_messages` table by `thread_id` and selecting `MAX(sent_at)`, then joining the result back onto the `users_messages` table to find the other fields of that maximum record.

I find that `NATURAL JOIN` is a very handy shortcut here:

```
SELECT   messages.message,
         users.username AS from_username,
         t.sent_at,
         t.count_thread_msgs,
         t.count_unread_msg
FROM     users_messages NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   thread_id,
           to_usr_id,
           MAX(sent_at)  AS sent_at,
           COUNT(*)      AS count_thread_msgs,
           SUM(NOT read) AS count_unread_msg
  FROM     users_messages
  WHERE    to_usr_id = ?
  GROUP BY thread_id
) t JOIN messages ON messages.id = users_messages.msg_id
    JOIN users    ON users.id    = users_messages.from_usr_id
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error "near 'read WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS count_unread_msg FROM users_messages ' at line 9"

Comment: The last comment was a mistake, sorry. I have tried your query but I am getting weird results. Take a look at the users_messages table: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43670983/users_messages_table.PNG and the results I get: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43670983/results2.png. As you can see the I get wrong results, there are 3 messages in thread_id 0 but I am getting only 2 and the unread messages are always the same as the messages count.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's interesting -- I get slightly different results in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6c1/1) (most notably, the unread count).  The reason that only 2 messages are showing in thread 0 is that only two were *sent to* the current user: it is therefore a count of the messages in that users' inbox (was this not what you wanted?).  If that restriction is removed, should it also be removed for the unread message count?  What about the 'most recent message sent time'?

Comment: My fault, I was not clear about that: 'count_thread_msgs' is the total number of messages in the thread, doesn't matter who sent it. 'count_unread_msg' is the number of unread messages that where sent to the specific user id (to_usr_id).

Comment: @Jonathan: Are you *sure* that you want the total messages in the thread, even if the user was not privy to one or more messages (i.e. neither sender nor recipient)?  Would this not cause every thread to be shown to every user ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6c1/2/0))?  And which should be the 'latest message' in your desired resultset: the latest in the thread, even if the user was neither sender nor recipient; the latest that they received; or the latest message to which they were a correspondent?

Comment: I think I am sure :) because there are always only two users related to a thread_id so its not a problem (if i understood your question right... mmm. i think i dont) and 'latest message' is simply the lastest message in the thread, doesn't matter who sent it to who, simply the latest one.

Comment: @Jonathan: Just add an `ORDER BY` clause to the end -- e.g. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6c1/5).

Comment: @Jonathan: Does that latest fiddle do what you wanted?  Do let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: It helped thanks! I am getting a hard time deciding if i give the bounty to you or to @Zane Bien. Both answers are working correctly and performance is similar...

Comment: @Jonathan: Zane's initial answer was closer to the mark than mine (but that was due to my misunderstanding of your requirements!) -- do feel free to award the bounty to him if you feel his answer is deserving. :)

Comment: I have re-read one of your comments and now I realize that 'latest message' needs to be the latest the user received, like you said! Can you help me out with that?

Comment: @Jonathan: What about the 'most recent message sent time'?

Comment: I think it needs to be the sent time related to the message displayed, (latest the user received).. but what happens when the message was sent by the user but he has recieved no replies? I want to display that also..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16468/discussion-between-eggyal-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
      users.id,
      users.username,
      user_messages.thread_id,
      user_messages.unread ,
      messages.message 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                 from_usr_id , 
                 msg_id,
                 count(thread_id)) as thread_id,
                 count(read_at) as  unread  
          FROM user_messages)as user_messages on user_messages.from_usr_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN messages on messages.id = user_messages.msg_id
```

Comment: I am not getting what i need with your query, i get strange results instead. I have only one thread in db but I get 3 rows returned, one with the correct values (i think) and two rows with nulls in all of the columns. plus i get thread_id as 2 when my thread_id is 1, i dont think this is working at all, sorry.

Comment: well change count columns according to your requirements

Comment: like i said, the count columns is not the only problem

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT   c.message,
         d.username AS from_username,
         b.sent_at,
         a.count_thread_msgs,
         a.count_unread_msg
FROM     (
         SELECT   MAX(id)  AS maxid,
                  COUNT(*) AS count_thread_msgs,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN `read` = 0 AND <uid> = to_usr_id THEN 1 END) AS count_unread_msg
         FROM     users_messages
         WHERE    <uid> IN (from_usr_id, to_usr_id)
         GROUP BY thread_id
         ) a
JOIN     users_messages b ON a.maxid       = b.id
JOIN     messages c       ON b.msg_id      = c.id
JOIN     users d          ON b.from_usr_id = d.id
ORDER BY b.sent_at DESC
```

---

This gets the latest message in each thread that the user `<uid>` started or is a part of.

The latest message is based on the highest `id` of each thread_id.

This solution makes the following assumptions:

- The `id` in `users_messages` is a unique auto-incrementing int for each new row.
- Each thread contains correspondence between never more than two users.

If the thread can contain more than two users, then the query will need to be slightly adjusted so as to derive an accurate count aggregation.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error "near 'read WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS count_unread_msg FROM users_messages ' at line 9"

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry. Try putting `read` between backticks: ( **`** ) because it's a MySQL reserved keyword. Solution adjusted.

Comment: @Jonathan, that's because you're supposed to replace "`<uid>`" with the specific user id you want to filter on. So if the user id was `5`, it has to be `WHERE 5 IN (from_usr_id, to_usr_id) ... ...`.

Comment: Great! Your query it getting good results, but there is a problem and that is my fault, I was not clear about that: 'count_thread_msgs' is the total number of messages in the thread, doesn't matter who sent it (working good) but 'count_unread_msg' is the number of unread messages that where sent to the specific user id (to_usr_id). That is because I want to show the user only his unread messages. Can you help me out with that too? :)

Comment: @Jonathan, see my updated solution with the new `CASE` expression for the `count_unread_msg` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know, change `$$` for your `user ID`..

```
select u.username,msg.message,m.sent_at,

(select count(*) from user_message where read=0 and to_usr_id=$$) as count_thread_msgs,

(select count(*) from user_message where to_usr_id= $$) as count_unread_msg

from users as u join user_messages as m

on u.id=m.id where u.id=$$
```

`join messages as msg on msg.id=m.id`

```
group by u.id;`
```

Comment: Not working, i dont see any references to the 'messages' table.

Comment: @Jonathan can you use SQLFiddle, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  m.message,
  u.username from_username,
  um1.sent_at,
  um2.count_thread_msgs,
  um2.count_unread_msg
FROM users_messages um1
  JOIN (
       SELECT
         thread_id,
          MAX(sent_at) sent_at,
          COUNT(*) count_thread_msgs,
          COUNT(IF(`read` = 1, `read`, NULL)) count_unread_msg
        FROM users_messages GROUP BY thread_id) um2
    ON um1.thread_id = um2.thread_id AND um1.sent_at = um2.sent_at
JOIN messages m
  ON m.id = um1.msg_id
JOIN users u
  ON u.id = um1.from_usr_id
-- WHERE u.id = 100 -- specify user id here
```

Answers on your questions:

1. About last datetime: I have changed query a little, just try new one.
2. About specific users: Add WHERE condition to filter users - `...WHERE u.id = 100`.
3. About many records: because you join another tables (`messages` and `users`), and there can be more then one record with the same `thread_id`. To avoid this you should group result set by `thread_id` field and use aggregate function to get single result, e.g. using GROUP_CONCAT function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the query works in some cases, but I have a few problems: 1) I am getting the first message of each thread instead of the last one. 2) I think its getting all the system messages, can you add another query that gets the threads for a specific user? (in order to show the user his messages). 3) I have 3  threads in my db but i am getting 5 rows of results. Hos is this possible?

Comment: I ahve attached two screenshots, one of the users_messages table and one of the results: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43670983/users_messages_table.PNG - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43670983/results.png